# Ada issue with STORAGE_ERROR

Tags: glibc, ada, gnat, memcmp

I have this small function that is causing me headaches on RHEL6, and I am not sure what is going on... and it is a pain to debug.   When I run this I am getting a STORAGE_ERROR, so I did a gstack to see where the program is hanging  (See below).    It looks like an issue with memcmp although I'm not sure where/how it is being called..  Any ideas for a workaround?

When I change this function to just return 'true' it seems to work fine (STORAGE_ERROR goes away), so I figure that the problem is with some logic in this part:  **(Ada.Characters.Handling.To_Upper(EPS_List(1).all) = "LOCALHOST");**

```
  function Localhost_Only return Boolean is
  --++
     EPS_List : String_List_Type 
              := Values(Bstring.To_Bounded_String("EPS"));
  begin
    return (Ada.Characters.Handling.To_Upper(EPS_List(1).all) = "LOCALHOST");

  end Localhost_Only;
```

**BEGIN EDIT*****

Another way that workst was doing this  (Moving it out of function scope... Why does this work?):

```
   EPS_List : String_List_Type 
              := Values(Bstring.To_Bounded_String("EPS"));

  function Localhost_Only return Boolean is
  --++

  begin
    return (Ada.Characters.Handling.To_Upper(EPS_List(1).all) = "LOCALHOST");

  end Localhost_Only;
```

**END EDIT*****

**gstack** output on the process:

```
Thread 1 (Thread 0x407059a0 (LWP 13610)):
#0  0x40000424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x00b2b2fc in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x0b53dd9e in system__tasking__stages__vulnerable_complete_master ()
#3  0x0b53e242 in system__tasking__stages__finalize_global_tasks ()
#4  0x0b5845d3 in __gnat_last_chance_handler ()
#5  0x0b545c50 in ada__exceptions__exception_traces__unhandled_exception_terminateXn ()
#6  0x0b5459de in ada__exceptions__exception_propagation__propagate_exceptionXn ()
#7  0x0b5465c5 in __gnat_raise_nodefer_with_msg ()
#8  0x0b5469ed in ada__exceptions__raise_with_location_and_msg ()
#9  0x0b5469b8 in __gnat_raise_storage_error_msg ()
#10 0x0b546f98 in __gnat_rcheck_31 ()
#11 0x0b5363de in system__interrupt_management__notify_exception ()
#12 <signal handler called>
#13 0x0bcef590 in memcmp@@GLIBC_2.0 ()
#14 0x084a83c9 in common_network_configuration__localhost_only ()
```

**Relevant types/function:**

```
type Number_Of_Items_Type is range 0 .. 250;

subtype Index_Type is Number_Of_Items_Type 
     range Number_Of_Items_Type'First + 1 .. Number_Of_Items_Type'Last;

type String_List_Type is array (Index_Type range <>) 
     of String_Access.String_P_Type;

package Bstring is new Ada.Strings.Bounded.Generic_Bounded_Length 
                            (Max => Line_Length_Type'last);

   function Values(Name : Bstring.Bounded_String) return String_List_Type is
   --++
   -- ABSTRACT
   --   Return a list of pointers to strings. The strings are all the values
   --   associated with the specified name. All values are recursively 
   --   evaluated so that each entry in the returned list is a primitive
   --   name (i.e. integer, ip_address, or unix_workstation).
   --
   --   If a circular definition is detected, an empty list is returned. 
   --
   -- LOCAL DATA
     -- Number of items in list
     Count    : Number_Of_Items_Type := 0;

     -- List of pointers to strings containing the primitive values
     Out_List : String_List_Type (1 .. Index_Type'Last);

     -- The Index of the item being evaluated
     Item     : Config_Index_Type := 0;

     -- A safety net, to detect and prevent unlimited recursion, such as 
     -- will happen in the case of a circular definition.
     Depth    : Number_Of_Items_Type := 0;

     procedure Find_Values (Name : in Bstring.Bounded_String) is
     --++ 
     -- ABSTRACT
     --   This procedure recursively calls itself until it makes it all 
     --   The way through the Config_Array without finding a match on the
     --   specified Name. The index of the last name for which a match was
     --   found is used to get the value associated with that Name. This 
     --   is a primitive value associated with the name and is added to the
     --   Out_List. 
     --
     --   Depth is used to count the recursion depth, when it reaches a 
     --   maximum, no more recursive calls are made, preventing an endless
     --   loop in the case of a direct or indirect circular definition.
     begin 
       Depth := Depth + 1;
       for Index in 1 .. Config_Count loop
         if  Name_Match(Bstring.To_String(Name),Index) 
         and Count < Number_Of_Items_Type'last 
         and Depth < Number_Of_Items_Type'last then
           Item := Index;
           Find_Values (Config_Array(Index).Value);
         end if;
       end loop;
       if Item /= 0 then
         if Count < Number_Of_Items_Type'last then
           Count := Count + 1;
           Out_List(Count) := Config_Array(Item).Val_Ptr;
         end if;
         Item := 0;
       end if;
     end Find_Values;

   begin -- Values
     Find_Values(Name);
     if Depth < Number_Of_Items_Type'last then
       return Out_List(1..Count);
     else 
       return Null_String_List;
     end if;
   end Values;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade the compiler on RHEL6..

Answer (score 2):

My absolute first guess here would be that `EPS_List(1)` isn't pointing to a valid memory location. Did you check that?

As near as I can tell, that array ultimately gets loaded from pointers out of something named `Config_Array`. So if that isn't initialized when the loading happens, or if the memory those pointers reference gets freed before `Localhost_Only` gets called, you would have errors of this nature.

This code is complex enough that I'd go into Localhost_Only and check on this. Either use the debugger to look at those pointers, or add debug code before your `return` statement to display their values.

Also, your `Localhost_Only` routine takes in an unconstrained array, then assumes it contains element `1`. If it doesn't, I believe you should get something like `Constraint_Error` or `Range_Error`, but if you turned off your compiler's range checking, `Storage_Error` could result instead. Either way, you should protect against that eventuality somehow. Something like `if EPS_List'length > 0 then return False; end if;`...

---

On your edit, my best guess for why moving the declaration prevents the crash is that this changes *when* that initialization happens. It now happens much earlier. Again, it might pay off to put it back into the crashing state and try to figure out with the debugger and/or debug print statements what exactly is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your help... can you take a look at my latest Edit too?  Moving the declaration out of function scope works... Any idea why would this be?